# Custom OSX service using an Automator action with 2 text input sources possible?

Tags: macos, automator

I want to set up a custom OSX service, available in an app's services menu, that extracts an address from a web page, adds some user text input, and writes both infos as a new contact into the address book.
I do now the following:
On the web page, I mark part of the text containing the address.
In Automator, I use "Separate text and data" from the text category, and extract the address.
The next step in Automator is an Obj-C action, developed in XCode, that inputs the address and converts it to a new contact entry of the address book.
This works, but I am not able to accept the additional user input. There is an action "Input text" in Automator's text category, but I don't know how to combine both text inputs (address & user input) as input to my Obj-C action.
**EDIT**:
Here is my Automator window:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you have got so far? Can your Obj-C accept a second parameter? Can you use "&" to join the two strings (maybe with a separator like "|" and separate them in Obj-C? Can you write the first string to a temporary file then append the second and pass the filename to Obj-C?

Comment: What I have now (I'm not experienced in Automator actions) is an Automator script that accepts formatted text, inputs it into an Automator action of the OSX library (category "text", name "Separate data and text"), that separates the address, and forwards it to my Obj-C action. This works. The problem is that I want additional input to my Obj-C action, text input by user, e.g. by an additional Automator action of the OSX library, but I don't know how to insert this additional input into the Automator sequence. So it is not a problem of my Obj-C action, but a problem of the Automator work flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your Obj-C program here, but I can get two lots of text from the user and store them in two separate variables like this, so I presume you can pass both variables to your Obj-C, can't you?

Maybe seeing this will help someone else understand what you are trying to do...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will edit my question to show you my Automator window (in German, sorry). Your approach to set variables holding the text inputs, and to pass them to an Obj-C action would probably solve my problem. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. My Automator workflow is now the following: 1) Receive text from any program, 2) Separate data and text, and extract the address, 3) Write the address in variable 1, 4) Ask for user text, 5) Write this text in variable 2, 6) Ask for the values of both variables, 7) Input both values into my Obj-C action, and save them to the address book. Again, thanks a lot!